# Getting Authenticated User and Pivot Table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

The code below is returning all my users in the database. I am looking to retrieve the logged in User with Services (many-to-many relationship).

```
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    dd(User::with('services')->find($user_id)->get()->toArray());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method already retrieves the `User` object. You're then calling `get()` on that `User` instance, which is what is retrieving a `Collection` of all the `Users`. To get your code to work, just remove the call to `get()`.

One note, though: `Auth::user()` is already an instance of your logged in user. There is no need to retrieve the user again. To access the services for that user, you can either explicitly load them using the `load()` method, or you can just access the `services` attribute which will be lazy loaded the first time it is used.

```
$user = Auth::user();
// explicitly loading the services:
$user->load('services');
dd($user->toArray());
```

or

```
$user = Auth::user();
// services will be lazy loaded on first access of the attribute
$services = $user->services;
dd($user->toArray());
```